# Is it possible to set MaximumBytesBilled on the BigQuery JDBC driver?

Tags: google-bigquery

When using tools like [DataGrip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9l2c_aQPoQ) to run queries in Google BigQuery it would be handy to be able to set the [MaximumBytesBilled](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#limit_query_costs_by_restricting_the_number_of_bytes_billed) property on the [Magnitude Simba JDBC driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/). This is a handy safety feature that would prevent users from running queries which would incur huge costs. Is this currently possible?